# How do I get the placeholder attribute into a Search API Solr Search field?

Tags: search

I'm using Search API Solr Search and can't seem to get a placeholder attribute in it. I've tried using hook form alter as I would on a normal search block, but doesn't seem to work with search api solr.

The id of the form = views-exposed-form-recipe-find-recipe-find-list 
The name of the search input field = search_api_views_fulltext

I've placed this function in my theme's template.php...

```
function marigold_institute_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form_recipe_find_recipe_find_list') {
    $form['search_api_views_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search by name or ingredient');
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. This is the first time I've tried using hook_form_alter, so I could easily be missing something obvious. I tried the function on a normal search block using "search_block_form" for the id and name, and it worked. I just can't seem to get it working with search api solr search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the views exposed filter form always has an ID of "views_exposed_form", nothing more specific. My low-rent way round it was this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['search_api_views_fulltext'])) {
    $form['search_api_views_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('blah');
  }
}
```

That works fine for my use case, but if you need something more specific you should be able to look in the `$form` or `$form_state` and find the View object, which you can use to identify which view/display is currently being altered.

Comment: How do I look in the $form or $form_state?

Comment: Install the Devel module if you haven't already, and use `dpm($form);`, that will print the array out to the messages area

Comment: Okay. It's not easy being such a newbie. Thank you for your help... 

I don't think I'm doing this right. I put dpm($form); on a new line in my template.php. I get a green area with a check in the messages area, but it's blank. There's no information.

Comment: It's working now. I found that I had a module that may have been interfering with it. It is a sandbox project https://drupal.org/sandbox/berliner/2087181 MEFIBS - More exposed forms in blocks. I disabled it, and I got the placeholder text. Then I went back, enabled MEFIBS again, and the placeholder text is still there! 

I'm glad that it's there and I got it working, but a little bummed that I'm not sure why... Still learning. Thanks again for the help.